# Using require() with Ionic V1

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, require, instamojo

I am building an e-commerce mobile application with Ionic V1. I am integrating Instamojo as the payment gateway provider. They provide a npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/instamojo-nodejs for integration with node applications. However, to us this module we have to make use of the require() functionality.

> var Insta = **require('instamojo-nodejs')**; Insta.setKeys(API_KEY,
>   AUTH_KEY);

While trying to use this, I get an error that require is undefined. Can someone, help me out with how to use this in an Ionic v1 app?

Comment: 1. Is this on the backend or frontend? 2. How are you starting your app?

Comment: did you found anything @vkm ?